# attempted to call method 'change' after enhanceWithin()

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to migrate to jqm 1.4 and having some issues with changePage. I have converted the code to use enhanceWithin() on the content div. I am using backbone to render content into the content div. Here is the content div

```
<div id='contentContainer'>
    <!--  dynamic templates will be inserted here -->
    <div id='content' class="content" data-role="content"></div>
  </div>

 // the router
 changePage : function(page, params) {
  // empty() is called in the render method;
  page.render(params);
  $('#content').enhanceWithin();//trigger.('create');
},
```

I still get the changePage issue, any thoughts?

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'change'

Comment: It appears this is happening when I call router.navigate(;router', {trigger:true]) on backbone router, somehow jqm is seeing the hash change and throwing this exception because there is no page with this id. I only want backbone to change the page not jqm. I do have hash settings set to false in jqm on startup

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this was caused by a setting that I had used in previous versions. For some reason $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#contentContainer'); was causing these errors, not sure why but if someone could explain that would be useful.